# Using DNF or YUM to install updates in Fedora 23

Tags: yum, dnf

Im using Fedora version 23 (latest upgrade and upates).  Currently to receive the updates, I use:

```
su -c 'yum update'
```

This works fine, but I get:

```
yum command has been deprecated, redirecting to '/usr/bin/dnf update'.
See 'man dnf' and 'man yum2dnf' for more information.
To transfer transaction metadata from yum to DNF, run:
'dnf install python-dnf-plugins-extras-migrate && dnf-2 migrate'
```

I have run `dnf install python-dnf-plugins-extras-migrate && dnf-2 migrate` with no errors.

I assume I should now be able to use:

```
dnf install update
```

However when I do, every time, I get:

```
Last metadata expiration check performed 0:59:08 ago on Fri Dec 18 17:30:42 2015.
No package update available.
Error: Unable to find a match.
```

Comment: I don't want to steal the answer, but they answered you here on the forums: http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?p=1750424

Answer (score 2):

`dnf install update` means you are trying to install a package named "update".  To apply all updates, just run `dnf update`.